# Adding data from SQLServer to XRLabels from DevExpress in VB NET using code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, devexpress

My DevExpress tools does not show on the toolbar and I cannot find a solution other than adding data using code. I have to create a Perscription Report for a veterinary so multiple tables are going to be used from the database.

Comment: You have to [restore toolbox](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/ka18574/how-to-resolve-issues-with-toolbox-items) first.

Answer (score 0):

If you have reinstalled Visual Studio or installed Visual Studio after the installation of our products, re-run our installer in **Repair** mode to register our toolbox items for that Visual Studio.

Refer this brief documentation to know that [How to resolve issues with Toolbox items](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/ka18574/how-to-resolve-issues-with-toolbox-items)